# How to get back to the sender of an event?

Tags: c#

I want to create a todo app in C# as homework and I am stuck in this problem. I created a UserControl to individual task have label for title of the task and two other labels to hold the details information.

The idea is in main form, I made the usercontrol in dynamic loop added when user add them

```
public void add_Item(string text, string key ,bool check)
    {
      Task_Item item = new Task_Item(text, key , check);
       item.Click += new EventHandler(this.detailesEvents);
       ContainerOfTaskPanel.Controls.Add(item);
     }
```

And then when click on one of therm appear a panel have the details of the usercontrol by sender object.

```
private void detailesEvents(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task_Item item = sender as Task_Item;
        taskHeaderLabel.Text = item.teskItemText.Text;
        onDayBtn.Click += new EventHandler(onDayBtn_Click);
        detailsPanelAnima.ShowSync(detailsPanel);
    }
```

and here I ran into problems. I want to add button to add (on my day) when click on it back to the usercontrol and write on the label event `OnDayBtn_Click`. I do not know how to write it to back to specific sender I was in to control it.

Comment: Adding `onDayBtn.Click` inside another eventhandler is almost certainly an error. Click on a Task_Item twice and you get 2 subscriptions.

Comment: I would love to know what you mean by "I do not know how to write it to back to specific sender I was in to control it." It's not at all clear. Can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: sorry because it was not clear what i mean when i am clicking in the button called OnDayBtn should write in the usercontrol label inder the title  "on Day"